# Allow Apps won't unlock in Security & Privacy - El Capitan

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

I am attempting to use an unsigned app. However, the options are grayed out under "Allow apps downloaded from". I did click the lock to unlock it, but still grayed out. I am an admin on my machine.

Is there a way that I can change that setting by editing a file?

Comment: On a Mac your admin privileges are either total or none, there is no finer delineation unless you are part of a corporate structure or subject to parental controls. If you can click the lock & provide the necessary credentials, you can change the setting.

Answer (score 1):

*Log in as Administrator*; *unlock the SystemPreferences->Security&Privacy Applet* (left bottom), then click the General tab when it is not already chosen: check the middle Allow line.
Hold the Alt/Option key while selecting/opening the App.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I have some administrator privileges. I do not however, have the Administrator password. I do believe though, that that setting should be in a file somewhere. Given that I have root (through sudo), I should be able to edit it, yes?